# Images not showing in a Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am building a Windows Store (WinRT) application, and I have added in buttons to manipulate items in a list, I am using images for these buttons. I have followed numerous sets of information but can't get these images to show up, I have tried the following:

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="/Images/add.png"/>
</Button>

<Button>
  <Image Source="mx-app://Images/add.png"/>
</Button>
```

I have tried the above with the image set to copy local, and then with different build actions, the image just never shows when I run the application.

Answer (score 3):

If you're including the images in the application package, they should be marked as Content (which they would by default when pulling adding them to the project).

Your first invocation should work, assuming you have a top level folder in your project called Images.

Your second invocation should be (it's just a more explicit version of the first):

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/add.png"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the build action on each image to Resource.

Then you should be able to write

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="/Images/add.png"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: This didn't work, I still get blank buttons when testing. I have made sure that the image is the correct location in the Debug folder as well as Debug\appx just in case, The image is never shown. so the structure of my debug folder that it runs from is this:  Debug\Images\add.png and Debug\Appx\Images\add.png. Neither of these images are used.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the image. Properties -> Build Action. Ensure That "Build Action" is Content